# Python: separating text into units and creating a list of the units

Tags: regex, list, python-2.7, split

I need to create a Python script that reads in a short text file, separates the text into units (paragraphs, sentences, words) and then prints out the text as a list of those units. Additionally, I want to be able to print out subsets of those lists (i.e. the first 15 elements, elements 8-10, etc.)

I'm new to programming. I've heard that this is much easier with NLTK, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this without NLTK first. This is what I currently have to split the paragraph into sentences... but I don't really know where to go from here and how to end up with a list of all of the units.

## Split up a paragraph into sentences

```
def para_to_sent(paragraph):
    import re
    sentence_end = re.compile('[.!?]')
    sentence_list = sentence_end.split(paragraph)
    return sentence_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = """Big Brother watching Big Brother is so meta. According to Deputy Attorney General James Cole, the National Security Agency "probably" gathers phone records of Congressional lawmakers and staff. Cole was grilled by members of Congress at a House Judiciary Committee hearing on Tuesday, and said that he was unaware of anything that "scrubbed out" Congressional numbers from the NSA's data sweeps. But don't worry, Cole added that NSA officials aren't allowed to look at the findings "unless we have reasonable, articulable suspicion that those numbers are related to a known terrorist threat."""
    sentences = para_to_sent(p)
    for s in sentences:
        print s.strip()
```

If this is a silly question, let me know! Just pointing me in the direction of solid resources would be super helpful!

Comment: You could use `\S+` to get the words, something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/mH6kY8). (And you can then clean up some more by removing some punctuations). You might also want to use `[.!?]+` for sentences (for ellipses `...`). For paragraphs, maybe split on newlines? `[\r\n]+`

Comment: Thanks, Jerry. This definitely helped a lot. The regex resource is super useful.